# Searching through *.class files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, decompiler, .class-file

Is it possible to search for terms (such as method names) in .class files (from Referenced Libraries) in eclipse (I am able to view them automatically with JD Java Decompiler, so if I go through various class files I can find what I'm looking for visually or by searching each individual file). I've had a similar question about locating classes and was told to use ctrl + alt + h, which allows you to locate the class hierarchy of a given class in a .class file, but that method does not seem to allow one to find interfaces by name or constructs such as methods or variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ctrl+H->Java Search->Search for Method`, etc, etc

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + H will bring up a Search/Find dialog. One of the tabs is Java which will let you specify what exactly you are looking for e.g. Class/MNethod etc.